# Multidimensional array sorting with key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this in PHP. I what to ordered by *amount* ascending:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trans_id] => PR58EC68AFE8B0F3186
            [bill_number] => 1
            [order_date] => 2017-04-11
            [amount] => 800
            [trx_type] => purchase
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [trans_id] => PR58EC68AFE8B0F3186
            [bill_number] => 1
            [order_date] => 2017-04-11
            [amount] => 150
            [trx_type] => purchase-paid
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [trans_id] => PR58EC68AFE8B0F3186
            [bill_number] => 1
            [order_date] => 2017-04-11
            [amount] => 100
            [trx_type] => purchase-paid
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [trans_id] => BL58EC68EC4BCA18805
            [bill_number] => 1
            [order_date] => 2017-04-11
            [amount] => 2000
            [trx_type] => bill
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as you can see, we're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts and we'll help you... But nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: sort array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813236/php-sort-array-by-value)

Comment: http://php.net/array_multisort example #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `usort()` built in function with your custom function like this

```
    <?php
$yourarray = array(
    0 => array(
        'bill_number' => 3,
        'amount' => 100
    ),
    1 => array(
        'bill_number' => 4,
        'amount' => 50
    ),
    2 => array(
        'bill_number' => 5,
        'amount' => 150
    ),
);

function sortByOrder($a, $b)
{
    return $a['amount'] - $b['amount'];
}

usort($yourarray, 'sortByOrder');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yourarray);
?>
```

then output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bill_number] => 4
            [amount] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bill_number] => 3
            [amount] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bill_number] => 5
            [amount] => 150
        )

)
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php